# Is it possible to convert an object to another object when both classes are identical?

Tags: c#

I have two webservices, one is GetCatDetails and the other is GetDogDetails.

They return a CatDetails and a DogDetails object.

Both of the objects are identical, the classes are identical except for name as under the hood they use the same database.

The web service queries the database, and retrieves the details, and populates all the fields and returns the object.

Is it deliberate that I have designed the webservice to return distinct objects rather than an AnimalDetails.

Rather than copy and paste this logic, is there any way to convert one to the other? Normally I would just use a base class to solve this, but I don't want it to affect the WSDL of the web service, because base classes might confuse it.

Any ideas? Perhaps there's a sneaky cheat way of doing it as they are literally identical classes except in name.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes it is... but in no good and performant way. You can serialize a DogDetails to xml and read it in as CatDetails. But pokes and Jakubs solution are waaaaaay better.

Comment: Same contents = same type PLUS a "category" field. Two identical but distinct types make little sense. Also, you won't have to copy-paste any and all edits you make to one type in the next 5 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, distinct classes represent distinct types, even if they have the same contents. You should use a type hierarchy here with an `AnimalDetails` at the top which contains all the shared data.

You can still return the specialized types from your webservice though while sharing code to construct them. For example consider the following type definitions:

```
class AnimalDetails
{
    public string Name
    { get; set; }
    public float Height
    { get; set; }
    public float Weight
    { get; set; }
}

class DogDetails : AnimalDetails
{ }
class CatDetails : AnimalDetails
{ }
```

Then you could still have distinct `GetDogDetails` and `GetCatDetails` webservices, while sharing some code to fill the objects:

```
public DogDetails GetDogDetails (int id)
{
    DogDetails dog = new DogDetails();
    QueryFromDatabase(dog, id);
    return dog;
}

public CatDetails GetCatDetails (int id)
{
    CatDetails cat = new CatDetails();
    QueryFromDatabase(cat, id);
    return cat;
}

private void QueryFromDatabase (AnimalDetails animal, int id)
{
    // fetch from database, and fill the animal object with the values
    var databaseData = FetchObject(id);
    animal.Name = databaseData.GetString("name");
    animal.Height = databaseData.GetFloat("height");
    animal.Weight = databaseData.GetFloat("weight");
}
```

Comment: The problem is the WSDL, the client will have to know about the base class and how it's derived/implemented with the return types, which is an extra layer of complexity I hoped to avoid. I'd rather fudge it a little my end by copying & pasting the logic twice and have the clients experience a clean WSDL with two simple objects I think.

Comment: I'd go the extra mile and make a `GetAnimalDetails` too for the other methods to invoke

Comment: @SLC Yes, you would have to tell the client that there is actually a base class which declares the *shared* data between those special types. But that is a *much cleaner* design than to actually copy the identical definition in multiple types. If you have two types that actually have a base type semantically, then you should express that syntactically in code too. It will help the client just as much because you can then share code there too!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to copy the values between instances of your two classes. Since AutoMapper uses convention-based rules there will be little code for you to write.

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively
>   complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to
>   another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so
>   why not invent a tool to do it for us?

Comment: AutoMapper uses reflection though, so it involves some kind of performance loss. If you have a clear type hierarchy as OP mentioned, you should just make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

SLC - I feel your pain. I have gone through the same thought process recently with references to web services being unable to share the same class definitions even though they are identical but for name. My preference would have been for the "add service reference" wizard to have intelligently identified that there was a commonly shared class in my code base which was fit for purpose rather than duplicate it. I'd love to know if there is a way to get this to work as advertised. Defining a class hierarchy was also not a viable solution for me - especially as I want to be able to use the proxy class added by the service reference and retain the advantage of being able to automatically update this reference without breaking code. **Pengu** alluded to the strategy I used in the end, and as I was already using XML serialization, I just added a new method to an XmlHelper class I had put together. The relevant method is called Reincarnate. For example of usage, to convert a cat of type Cat to a dog of type Dog, the code is:

```
Dog dog = XmlHelper.Reincarnate<Cat, Dog>
                    (cat, defaultNamespace: "http://namespace");
```

I have included the relevant methods of the helper class below. I hope you find it useful:

```
 public class XmlHelper
 {

    public static string SerializeToXmlString<T>(T objectToSerialize, Dictionary<string, string> xmlNamespaces = null,
        string defaultNamespace = null)
    {
        StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlStringBuilder, xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            var xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            if (xmlNamespaces != null)
            {
                foreach (var xmlNamespace in xmlNamespaces)
                {
                    xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add(xmlNamespace.Key, xmlNamespace.Value);
                }
            }
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            if (defaultNamespace != null)
                xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialize, xmlSerializerNamespaces);
        }
        return xmlStringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlText, string defaultNamespace) where T : class
    {
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlText))
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
            return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as T;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert one object type to another which has a consistent serialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Source Class</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="U">Target Class</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectToReIncarnate">Source Object of Class Type T</param>
    /// <param name="xmlNamespaces">Namespace mappings to add to serialization, if required</param>
    /// <param name="defaultNamespace">Default namespace of serialized class</param>
    /// <returns>Target Object of Class Type U</returns>
    public static U Reincarnate<T,U>(T objectToReIncarnate, Dictionary<string, string> xmlNamespaces = null,
        string defaultNamespace = null) where U : class 
    {
        string serializedObject = SerializeToXmlString(objectToReIncarnate, xmlNamespaces, defaultNamespace);
        return Deserialize<U>(serializedObject, defaultNamespace);
    }

}
```

Comment: Another reason for keeping them distinct is that they can change. Clients have a tendency to decide they don't like something and want it changed, and some clients only have access to one of the services. I've made so many changes that clients demanded for (sometimes they paid for them) and if you have a separate class for everything it makes it much easier when suddenly your identical functionality between two services isn't identical anymore. Clever bit of code!